# Fitting a set of points to a distribution by adding up to three degrees of freedom with Python

Tags: gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, chi-squared-distribution, polynomial

I have a set of points whose shape is as below:
[image]

Its set of x and y points is as follows: x=[0.14741,0.180288,0.195,0.245342,0.25614,0.289377,0.315789,0.357143,0.431034,1.785714,2,2.323529,2.586207,3,3.894737,4.923077] y=[0.211718,0.408906,0.507768,0.832,0.903626,1.092787,1.368377,1.750082,2.593839,1.72126,1.653633,1.567115,1.502963,1.419437,1.279676,1.153634]

Can anyone fit a distribution with at least three degrees of freedom to these points? Do I need the name of the distribution and its coefficients? Does anyone have an idea of writing code with Python to get the coefficients and type of distribution? This chart is the most similar to the chi-square and Double Exponential charts.

I tried to write a polynomial for it by interpolation, which has a high degree.
This code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# Given data points
x = [0.14741, 0.180288, 0.195, 0.245342, 0.25614, 0.289377, 0.315789, 0.357143, 0.431034, 1.785714, 2, 2.323529, 2.586207, 3, 3.894737, 4.923077]
y = [0.211718, 0.408906, 0.507768, 0.832, 0.903626, 1.092787, 1.368377, 1.750082, 2.593839, 1.72126, 1.653633, 1.567115, 1.502963, 1.419437, 1.279676, 1.153634]
# Fit a polynomial equation of degree 5
p = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(x, y, 5))
# Generate a range of x values to plot the polynomial curve
x_new = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)

# Plot the data points and the polynomial curve
plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='Original data')
plt.plot(x_new, p(x_new), '-', label='Polynomial fit')

# Add axis labels and a legend
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

and the result of the code is.
[image]

can help me?